# How to replace number in csv with a string with python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to fix the first row of a CSV file. If column name in header starts from anything other than a-z, NUM has to be prepended. The following code fixes the special characters in each column of the first row but somehow can't get the !a-z.

```
path = ('test.csv')

for fname in glob.glob(path):

    with open(fname, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(reader) 
        header = [column.replace ('-','_') for column in header]
        header = [column.replace ('[!a-z]','NUM') for column in header]
```

what am I doing wrong. Please provide suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: `str.replace` does not take regex patterns. You want `re.sub` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
# csv file: 
# 2Hello, ?WORLD
# 1, 2

import csv
with open("test.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    print("Original header", header)
    header = [("NUM" + header[indx][1::]) for indx in range(len(header)) if not header[indx][0].isalpha()]
    print("Modified header", header)
```

Output:

```
Original header ['2HELLO', '?WORLD']
Modified header ['NUMHELLO', 'NUMWORLD']
```

The above list comprehension is equivalent to the following for loop:

```
 for indx in range(len(header)):
        if not header[indx][0].isalpha():
            header[indx] = "NUM" + header[indx][1::]
```

If you want to replace only numbers, then use the following:

```
if header[indx][0].isdigit():
```

You can modify this according to your requirements in case if it changes based on many relevant string functions.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to replace the 'column.replace' portion with something along these lines:

```
re.sub(r'[!a-z]', 'NUM', column)
```

The full documentation reference is here for specifics: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html 
https://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html

Comment: And the `!` needs to be replaced with `^`.

Comment: well I replaced with header = re.sub([^a-z'], 'NUM', str(header)), but another issue is it splits each word column and throws them individually in separate columns.

Comment: You would need to do something like this to make the `re.sub()` approach work: `re.sub(r'^([^a-z])', r'NUM\1', header)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you want to *prepend* 'NUM', you could do something like this (which could be more efficient, but this shows the basic idea).

```
import string

column = '123'

if column[0] not in string.ascii_lowercase:
    column = 'NUM' + column

# column is now 'NUM123'
```